Shell script not working when run as wsrep_notify_cmd by Galera Cluster for MariaDB
I have a simple shell script that I'm trying to use to test Galera Cluster for MariaDB's node state change notification mechanism, running on an AWS Ubuntu 20.04 LTS instance.  The script is a stripped down one based on the example script provided by Galera:
#!/bin/sh -eu

echo "Node Status Change:" > /home/ubuntu/Notification.txt

while [ $# -gt 0 ]
do
   case $1 in
      --status)
         echo "  STATUS=$2" > /home/ubuntu/Notification.txt
         shift
         ;;
      --uuid)
         echo "  CLUSTER_UUID=$2" > /home/ubuntu/Notification.txt
         shift
         ;;
      --primary)
         echo "  PRIMARY=$2" > /home/ubuntu/Notification.txt
         shift
         ;;
      --index)
         echo "  INDEX=$2" > /home/ubuntu/Notification.txt
         shift
         ;;
      --members)
         echo "  MEMBERS=$2" > /home/ubuntu/Notification.txt
         shift
         ;;
         esac
         shift
   done

exit 0

When I run this script myself from the command-line it works as expected, and the echo command arguments are written to /home/ubuntu/Notification.txt.  But when the Galera notification mechanism executes it it fails with (datetime header stripped for brevity):
 /etc/mysql/scripts/wsrep_notify.sh: 3: cannot create /home/ubuntu/Notification.txt: Directory nonexistent

I'm logged on as the same user that MariaDB is running as, and the permissions for /home/ubuntu/Notification.txt are -rw-rw-rw-.
I tried replacing #!/bin/sh -eu with #!/bin/bash, which also executes correctly from the command-line.  But that fails when executed by Galera with these errors:
/etc/mysql/scripts/wsrep_notify.sh: line 3: /home/ubuntu/Notification.txt: No such file or directory
/etc/mysql/scripts/wsrep_notify.sh: line 9: /home/ubuntu/Notification.txt: No such file or directory
/etc/mysql/scripts/wsrep_notify.sh: line 13: /home/ubuntu/Notification.txt: No such file or directory
/etc/mysql/scripts/wsrep_notify.sh: line 17: /home/ubuntu/Notification.txt: No such file or directory
/etc/mysql/scripts/wsrep_notify.sh: line 21: /home/ubuntu/Notification.txt: No such file or directory
/etc/mysql/scripts/wsrep_notify.sh: line 25: /home/ubuntu/Notification.txt: No such file or directory

The errors are similar enough that it seems like the underlying cause is the same in both cases, but I'm stumped as far as what that cause could be.  The script is clearly executing, so security on the script file isn't an issue.
Thoughts?

How about creating the directory and using twice the same directory?
if [[ ! -d  /home/ubuntu ]]; then
    mkdir -p  /home/ubuntu
fi


The directory already exists (though my original post erroneously included the Dan subdirectory in a couple of instance, which was from a different set of attempts...I've corrected that error).  And in fact, I indicate in my post that the Notification.txt file already exists as well.

It still complains, that not even /home/ubuntu exists there.

Systemd services protect the /home directory by default.
Access can be granted with:
sudo systemctl edit mariadb.service

And putting the following in the file.
[Service]

ProtectHome=false

ref: MariaDB KB Systemd
It is however a useful protection and redesigning the need for /home access is recommended.

Thank you!  This cost me nearly 2 days of pulling out my already thinning hair.  It seems like these sorts of things ought to be at least mentioned in the Galera or MariaDB web sites' descriptions for the wsrep_notify_cmd option and/or the example script provided by Galera, and yet it isn't (or at least not in any of the online documentation I was able to find).
